# Read 2D barcode encoded with base256

Tags: .net, vb.net, encoding, character-encoding, barcode-scanner

I have to read a 2D barcode that's encoded with base256. When I scan the barcode, it sends different characters as it comes from the keyboard and it changes the focus, turns visual studio in full screen, give the command to send to printer from notepad++.

I guess it reads ALT + TAB, CTRL + P, ALT + SHIFT, etc. and i can't capture all the bytes from the barcode.

I tried to capture the event on textbox KeyPress method with e.handled = True and e.keyChar added to the bytes()

On form.load I set:

```
Me.KeyPreview = True
```

And tried also on form.KeyDown with no luck.

Can anyone help me on this issue? 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I scan the barcode with a barcode scanner. I do not process any image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this done, I had to change the interface of the barcode reader to R232 and emulate a com port.